# uWSGI + Python subprocess does not execute shell command

Tags: python, subprocess

uwsgi + Python subprocess

Hello everyone,

I am trying to run a simple command in shell using Python subprocess module, everything works fine till I put 
uwsgi on the top. I also use flask as web framework.

Here is very simplified part of the  code

```
if request.method == 'POST':  

            testquery = subprocess.run( "ifconfig", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True )
            whoisresults=whoisquery.stdout
            print(whoisresults)
```

I was getting following error : /bin/sh: 1: ifconfig: not found

I replaced "ifconfig" with the full path where Python virtual evn runs.

```
testquery = subprocess.run( "/home/net/netools/netoolsenv/bin ifconfig", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True )
            whoisresults=whoisquery.stdout
            print(whoisresults)
```

But it still does not work, just error is different - /bin/sh: 1: /home/net/netools/netoolsenv/bin: Permission denied

Can anyone please advice in what direction should I dig? I am beginner here.

Comment: Permission Denied suggests that you don't have permissions over that file. Also "/home/net/netools/netoolsenv/bin ifconfig path seems invalid", I think you should remove the space

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with uWSGI. Also, why the `shell=True` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was getting following error : `/bin/sh: 1: ifconfig: not found`

uWSGI daemon usually run as another user, and this user has no `PATH` set. Use full absolute path to `ifconfig`.

To find full path to your tools, use `which`, e.g. run this command at your terminal:

> ```
> $ which ifconfig
> /usr/bin/ifconfig
> ```

and use that full path to `ifconfig` in your Python script.

> ```
> testquery = subprocess.run( "/usr/bin/ifconfig", shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True )
> ```